# dbcc checkdb runs for interminably long time, 50% of the time

Tags: sql-server, ola-hallengren, dbcc-checkdb, sql-server-2019, waits

I've got a nightly maintenance job (largely taken from the ola hallengren maintenance package) that runs database backups and runs an an integrity check on every database.

The integrity check part is running online, against production dbs, and usually completes in about ~2.5 hours - but sometimes it runs for much, much longer (12+ hours in some instances).

There aren't any other scheduled jobs or other activity that is running on the days where it hangs vs. the days where it doesn't, and the db it's usually hanging on is only about 170gb.

I took a look at my wait stats:[image]

And my write stalls: [image]

But I'm not a DBA by training and am not sure what to actually *do* about this information, or if it's even where I should be looking for this particular issue.

#### Additional Information Added From Comments

**sys.dm_exec_query_memory_grants**

requested_memory_kb = 31678040
granted_memory_kb = 31678040
required_memory_kb = 512

**sys.dm_exec_requests**

granted_query_memory = 3959755

**SQL Server DB Size & Memory**

Total size of all DB's on server is ~500 GB, but the particular database it is choking on is 169.6 GB. Max server memory allocated to SQL is 224 GB, total VM memory is 265 GB.

Comment: Ok so from memory grant it seems fine. I would look at disk latency on tempdb. I believe this may be causing the issue.

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. Please add relevant information to the question by clicking on the [edit] button. Could you add the relevant configuration settings for Ola's scripts? If you can add the schedules of the individual Ola jobs that are running, then that would be a bonus. The schedules might be a hint that the `INDEX REORGANIZE / REBUILD` is kicking in, while the the `DBCC CHECKDB` is running. If your database is REBUILDING indexes and you aren't using the Enterprise Edition then they will be built ONLINE, which can hinder performance. Enterprise Edition allows `OFFLINE` rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Was there an error from CHECKDB for those occasions when it took so long? Anything useful in the errorlog file for those occasions?

If CHECKDB find an error, it might do a "deep dive" to further investigate (traverse the linked list for the index instead of just checking a bitmap, mentioned here: https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/checkdb-from-every-angle-complete-description-of-all-checkdb-stages/).

Answer (score 0):

I looks like 'Avg Stall(ms)' is very high, I believe that the recommendation is for reads to be <15ms and writes <1ms, and the average's at 355ms for some of the temp files..

Maby you could measure disk latency with perfmon while DBCC is running: https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/archive/blogs/askcore/measuring-disk-latency-with-windows-performance-monitor-perfmon

If the disks are a problem then keeping data, logs and tempdb files on different (physical) disks might help.